# Can only open 2 concurrent sql connections (asp.net VB)

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I have a very complex data structure within a web application that im working on, which requires 3 connections at once to a MSSQL database, id rather not but its the only way to achieve what is required for now.

I set my connectionstrings in web.config as such:

```
      <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Foo_mainConnectionString1" connectionString="Data Source=GDE-WK-003\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Foo_main;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Foo_mainConnectionString2" connectionString="Data Source=GDE-WK-003\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Foo_main;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="Foo_mainConnectionString3" connectionString="Data Source=GDE-WK-003\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Another_FOO;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When set up as above (2 connections to the same DB) it works fine (although the third ' Another_FOO' is an unused one from a discontinued part of the project.

So in order to get another connection established, i changed "Another_FOO" to "Foo_Main"
Giving me 3 connections to the same DB.

On trying to run the website, it now seems that none of the connections are established.

Any ideas why this might be? Is there likely to be a connection limit that i cant find?

Comment: have you run SQL Profiler on it?

Comment: no - im using sql server express 2012, cant seem to find the thing...!

Comment: profiler isn't installed with express, you can install the full management tools for it, see http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: When you you say none of the connections are established, what exactly do you mean? Do you get an exception? Does it time out? Some more details would help.